# How to set a cursor to new line in JavaScript string?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a program where all the data from the table has to get into txt file in a specific way.
The idea is to have loop that would ad a new row of data (string) to my string (textFile) and then write it all into txt file. But what I need is to write every row into new line. In my case niether "/n" nor /n doesn't work. How do I do that? Write every new row in a new line. Thanks

This is what I've tried:

```
for(i=0; i < $('#table tr').length; i++ ){
    textFile = textFile + number + vendorID + amount + date + invoiceNum + fund + deptID + "3700  " + description+/n;
}
```

Comment: Try it with `\n`, also put it in quotation marks, as it would be normal text

Comment: Shuldn't it be:
textFile = textFile + number + vendorID + amount + date + invoiceNum + fund + deptID + "3700  " + description+"\n";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The escape character is actually the other slash, `\n`. Try this:

```
for(i=0; i < $('#table tr').length; i++ ){
    textFile = textFile + number + vendorID + amount + date + invoiceNum + fund + deptID + "3700  " + description + "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The character for escaping characters is backslash '\'not slash '/'
You will need to put the \n in quotes as it is a string.

If your editor, you are trying to view the text file in, is notepad you will need an additional carriage return for the line break to show as notepad needs newline and carriage return for a line break.
Your code would then look like this:

> for(i=0; i < $('#table tr').length; i++ ){
>       textFile = textFile + number + vendorID + amount + date + invoiceNum + fund + deptID + "3700  " + description + "\r\n";
>   }

Comment: Isn't this OS specific?

Comment: You are right it is mostly in Windows that the programs expect the additional \r. And in some editors the \r will show as a ^M or something like that. There are tools like unix2dos, and dos2unix that help converting between \r\n and \n line endings.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using textFile as `$element.text(textFile)` the new line symbol is `\n`